# List retrieving from firebase

Tags: java, android, listview, firebase

I know how to fetch a simple list but having problems when the nodes are nested like if a user enters in a textbox that he wants the list of students of Section1 then only Jerry and Sean with his roll no should be shown.
This is my code for a simple list.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ListView listView;
DatabaseReference dref;
ArrayList<String> list=new ArrayList<>();
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListView);
    adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    dref= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    dref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            String value=dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            list.add(value);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String value=dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            list.remove(value);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

JSON tree:

[image]

Please suggest me how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're attaching your `ChildEventListener` to the root of your database, your `onChildAdded` will be invoked with a snapshot for each section. So once for `Section1`, once for `Section2`, and once for `Section3`.

If you want to only listen on a specific section, attach your listener to that section:

```
dref= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
dref.child("Section1").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        String key = dataSnapshot.getKey();
        int value  = dataSnapshot.getValue(Integer.class);
        list.add(key+": "+value);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

In the above, since you're only listening to `Section1`, your `onChildAdded` will fire once for `Jerry` and once for `Sean`. But those are now the *keys* of the snapshots, so the code uses `getKey()`.

On the other hand: if you want to show students for all sections, you 
 need to keep your listener on the root and access lower level properties of the original snapshot. For this you either use `getChild()` to get to the property, or loop over `getChildren()` to access all properties.

```
dref= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
dref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        for (DataSnapshot student: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String value=student.getValue(String.class);
            list.add(value);
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Comment: Is there any way to show both name and value like in my list it is only showing roll no.And thank you very much for the solution

Comment: I updated the first snippet to use `getKey()` and `getValue(Integer.class)` to get the name and value.